# How to get the values at the pixels of a bokeh image glyph in hover tool?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, bokehjs, histogram2d

I have generated a bokeh 2d-histogram plot as mentioned in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50989390/11973173). The code and respective image is given below. In the code, the count of data-points per bin is in the entries in `H`. How can I get access to an individual `pixel-index` to get the value at respective index in `H` and show it in the `hover-text`? I want to show `count: 2` in the `hover-text` below `x` and `y` values, say. I tried using `image_index` mentioned [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/tools.html#basic-tooltips); probably new in **Bokeh 3.0.1** but not sure how it works.

**Note**: It would be better to get an answer compatible with **Bokeh 2.4.3** due to legacy code issues. Including `holoviews` tag as I know their outputs can be rendered as `bokeh figure`.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Turbo256
from bokeh.models import ColorBar, LinearColorMapper

a = np.array([1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([15, 16, 20, 35, 45, 50])
H, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(a, b, bins=5)

data=dict(
    image=[H],
    x=[xe[0]],
    y=[ye[0]],
    dw=[xe[-1]-xe[0]],
    dh=[ye[-1]-ye[0]]
)

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("x", "$x"),
    ("y", "$y"),
#     ("image_index", "$image_index"),
]

p = figure(x_range=(min(xe),max(xe)), y_range=(min(ye),max(ye)), tools="pan,reset,hover", tooltips=TOOLTIPS)

color_map = LinearColorMapper(palette=Turbo256, low=1, high=H.max(), low_color='white')
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_map, label_standoff=12)

p.image(source=data,image='image',x='x',y='y',dw='dw',dh='dh',color_mapper=color_map,)

p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

show(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the raw Bokeh code to do this, but in HoloViews it's:

```py
import numpy as np, holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

a = np.array([1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([15, 16, 20, 35, 45, 50])
H, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(a, b, bins=5)

img = hv.Image(H[::-1], bounds=(-1,-1,1,1), vdims=['image_index'])

img.opts(tools=['hover'], width=500, cmap="Turbo", colorbar=True, 
         clim=(1,None), clipping_colors={'min': 'white'})
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is there any way to modify the hover-text. Say I want to change `z` to some other name like `Count`?

Comment: Sure; ['x','y'] is the default `kdims` and I've updated hv.Image above to specify a non-default vdim (value dimension; anything beyond the two index or independent dimensions here).